# How to exactly identify email sender?

Tags: email, security, spoofing

We have a web app that is able to interact with users by email messages. So a user sends a email message to us then we identify user by **from/sender fields** from header. 
But I detected headers fields can easy be **spoofed**!
Is it possible somehow exactly identify email of sender? Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

E-mail protocol doesn't provide security. There are no standard ways to protect the header fields.
A sender can attach some secret code on each letter but it's not e-mail protocol scope.